# ASP.NET 5 - build image and run container outside of visual studio

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I created standard ASP.NET Core Web API .NET 5 project in .NET with Docker file automatically created. I did not select option "Configure for HTTPS".

When I run this project as docker container from Visual Studio then everything is fine, I can access swagger UI and hit RESRT API endpoints.

When I build the image and run it manually then it does not work.

I build it like this:

```
D:\temp\WebApplication1>docker image build -t kicaj29/webapplication1:1.0.0 -f WebApplication1/Dockerfile .
```

and run like this

```
docker run -p 8855:80 kicaj29/webapplication1:1.0.0
```

The container is running but when I try to access it using address http://localhost:8855/swagger/index.html then I get info that the page cannot be found.

Probably Visual Studio adds some extra staff but I cannot identify it.

Any ideas how to solve it?

-Jacek

Comment: Do you get any error messages when you run it? Does it say that it's listening on port 80?

Comment: I do not get any errors and pod is running:

docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS             PORTS                                                                                NAMES
786da26ae71c   kicaj29/webapplication1:1.0.0   "dotnet WebApplicati…"   29 seconds ago      Up 8 seconds       0.0.0.0:8855->80/tcp, :::8855->80/tcp                                                awesome_bose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Swagger to be available, you need to run the app in development mode. You do that by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable to 'Development'. If you change the docker run statement to

```
docker run -p 8855:80 -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development kicaj29/webapplication1:1.0.0
```

When you do that, the Swagger UI becomes available on http://localhost:8855/swagger

You can also add the line

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

to your Dockerfile. Then it'll be in development mode by default.